# Getting value of a column of gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to take a control as column in the TemplateFeilds of Gridview and it should not be hidden. There is a Button in the end of every column. My question is that what control i should use and how to get the value of specific row of that column where a Button is clicked  in the Gridview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `HiddenField` as column in the `GridView` because the control wont be visible and thus fulfil your requirement.
The code behind will be inside the row command of gridview

```
   public  void gdView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.CommandName == "sendvalue")
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < gdView.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    int getrow = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

                    HiddenField HiddenField1 = (HiddenField)gdView.Rows[getrow].FindControl("HiddenField1");
}
}
```

> where e.CommandName == "sendvalue" is because the atrribute command
>   name of Button is set to be "sendvalue"

HiddenField in design will be as

```
  <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

What value do you want to get?

You can handle the button's click event and cast the `sender` to `Button` and it's `NamingContainer` to `GridViewRow`. Then you have all you need to find all the other controls in that row.

```
protected void Button1_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get the button reference
    Button btn = (Button) sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow) btn.NamingContainer;
    // assuming the primary key value is stored in a hiddenfield with ID="HiddenID"
    HiddenField hiddenID = (HiddenField) row.FindControl("HiddenID");
    int id = int.Parse(hiddenID.Value);
}
```

aspx (GridView's TemplateField)

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Click Me" OnClick="Button1_Clicked"/>
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("PrimaryKeyField") %>'/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use hidden field in your template.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your approach by setting the `CommandArgument` property, of the button that will be clicked, to the value you want during row data binding.